# Firebase WebApp with Google SignIn only with specific domains and specific users

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am trying to add Google SignIn to my Firebase Webapp and according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin#advanced-handle-the-sign-in-flow-manually) this is done via

```
firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider); // using the google provider
```

and then handling the redirect result.

However I would like to limit this only to users of a specific domain `mycomany.com` and then I
would also like to whitelist specific users in the firebase authentication who can access the webapp.

How can I combine those two (three) specification if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict the domains that can be used to sign in to your project with Firebase authentication, you can set them at Firebase console > Authentication > Sign in methods > [Authorized domains in the Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/providers).

Also see Peter's answer here: [Confusing Auth domain setting in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48681989/confusing-auth-domain-setting-in-firebase)

Comment: so does this also work when using the ``firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider)``? But that would mean that ALL users can access the webapp and I can not whitelist some of them right?

Comment: There is no way to only allow certain users to register in Firebase Authentication at the moment.

Comment: Hey @zlZimon. Anything else needed here? I understand this may not be the answer you hoped for, but I hope it was still helpful.